# HTML textbox value always returns an empty string at asp.net button click event

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox

I have a simple stopwatch application which updates HTML textbox values using a javascript.

```
<form name="clock">
       <input type="text" size="12" name="stwa" value="00 : 00 : 00" style="texalign:center"/>
       <input type="text" size="12" name="stwb" style="text-align:center" /><br />
       <input type="button" name="theButton" onClick="stopwatch(this.value);" value="Start" />
       <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="resetIt();reset();" />     

       </form>
```

I also have an asp.net button control which should submit value in 'stwb' at the button click. Although stwb textbox gets updated with the javascript correctly, it always returns an empty string at button click.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

     <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click"/>

</form>
```

Button click event for the method.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strValue = Page.Request.Form["stwb"].ToString();
        Response.Write(strValue);
    }
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms; HTML forms submit independently.

Thus, when your server form submits, the data for your "clock" form is not passed as part of the request.

The easiest solution is probably to place your clock inside the form with the `runat=server` attribute.